# Translating DropTarget decorator to ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next, react-dnd

I am going through examples of `react-dnd`. Something I've never used before is passing props into HOC functions using ES6 syntax.

```
@DropTarget(props => props.accepts, boxTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  isOver: monitor.isOver(),
  canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
}))
export default class TargetBox extends Component {
  ...
}
```

How do I implement this using ES6 syntax? I get undefined props when I just pass it as an argument like this.

```
export default DropTarget(props.accepts, boxTarget, collect)(TargetBox);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [decorator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#decorators) and would translate to this:

```
export default DropTarget(props => props.accepts, boxTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver: monitor.isOver(),
    canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
}))(TargetBox);
```

Comment: If it's a proposal then it's not part of ES7 (ES2016).

Comment: @FelixKling Hmm, yeah. Wasn't it supposed to be in ES7 but scrapped? I'm used to calling  it ES7 but it was removed from staging.